# Redirect domain.com/folder with www to non-www and at the same time http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdirectory, no-www

I have installed into a sub-folder of my domain a Web App.
Example: domain.com/webapp

I want to use the Web App with SSL enabled: https://domain.com/webapp

I want to redirect at same time: WWW to NON-WWW and HTTP to HTTPS only for the sub-folder "webapp".

Trying with the code fund in this website didn't actually work 100%, having issues with to many redirects, or redirecting me to the site root not subfolder, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside **`/webapp/.htaccess`** use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. This is perfect, doesn't interact with other installations in the domain's folders or with the main domain installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your .htacess file in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^webapp/?(.*?)$ https://example.com/webapp/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have htaccess file inside the `webapps` folder, then you can try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webapps
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @MariusModoranu Where is your .htaccess file? And what exactly doesn't work? What is it doing or not doing? I also updated my answer.

Comment: Some of the links were taking my to the https://domain.com and I prefer  editing the .htaccess in domain.com/webapp

Comment: @MariusModoranu why are you unaccepting the answers? You do know that if both answers have helped you, you can at least up vote the answer.